# Delete multiple files from digitalocean spaces using aws-sdk/client-s3

Tags: node.js, aws-sdk, digital-ocean, aws-sdk-js, digital-ocean-spaces

I want to delete multiple files from digitaloceans spaces but keep getting errors. Environmental variables are all set
**My current code:**

```
const { S3Client, DeleteObjectsCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
require("dotenv").config();

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: "sfo3", 
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.DO_SPACES_KEY, 
    secretAccessKey: process.env.DO_SPACES_SECRET, 
  },
  endpoint: process.env.DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT,
  forcePathStyle: true, // Required for some S3-compatible services
});

const deleteFile = async (keys) => {
  try {
    const keys = [
      "1702039720121672541410-file_example_JPG_2500kB.jpg",
      "1702034408592871178538-file_example_PNG_2100kB.png",
      "1702034501011992084344-file_example_PNG_3MB.png",
    ];
    const keysArray = [];
    keys.map((key) => keysArray.push({ Key: key }));
    console.log(keysArray);
    const deleteParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.DO_SPACES_NAME, 
      Delete: {
        Objects: keysArray,
        // Quiet: false, 
      },
    };

    const command = new DeleteObjectsCommand(deleteParams);
    const data = await s3.send(command).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error deleting file:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

module.exports = deleteFile;
```

**Getting this error**

```
NotImplemented: UnknownError
    at throwDefaultError (C:\Users\username\Desktop\skrink-image\backend\node_modules\@smithy\smithy-client\dist-cjs\default-error-handler.js:8:22)
{
  '$fault': 'client',
  '$metadata': {
    httpStatusCode: 501,
    requestId: 'tx0000016e999caa939aed5-00657a18e7-3c6e5030-sfo3a',
    extendedRequestId: undefined,
    cfId: undefined,
    attempts: 1,
    totalRetryDelay: 0
  },
  Code: 'NotImplemented',
  RequestId: 'tx0000016e999caa939aed5-00657a18e7-3c6e5030-sfo3a',
  HostId: '3c6e5030-sfo3a-sfo3-zg01'
}
```

Any help would be appreciated
Tried by commenting `forcePathStyle: false` but still not deleting files
I also tried to do it using aws-sdk but with no luck

My package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "nodemon server.js",
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.472.0",
    "@img/sharp-win32-x64": "^0.33.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1515.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^16.3.1",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.2.0",
    "joi": "^17.11.0",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.6.5",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.3",
    "nodemon": "^3.0.2",
    "sequelize": "^6.35.1",
    "sharp": "^0.33.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, can you share your `package.json`?

Comment: Following this one more our of curiosity. i.e. is Digital Ocean ( a prominent brand in the digital space ) merely a marketing abstraction layer on the core underlying infrastructure. Seems a hell of a gamble from a strategic perspective which is akin to following (not sure of the gambling term) a Blackjack player at a table to win off their win.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I just added my package.json file also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed the issue. The issue was not in the code but with the endpoint. For upload, I was using an endpoint which was provided by default from Digitalocean like
`https://[spacename].nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com`.

It worked for uploading file and single deleting files. But not for deleting multiple objects. I had to use this endpoint for deleting `https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com` and before the file name I provided a space name like `[spacename]/image1.png`. So my code will look like this

```
const { S3Client, DeleteObjectsCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");
require("dotenv").config();

const s3 = new S3Client({
  region: "sfo3", 
  credentials: {
    accessKeyId: process.env.DO_SPACES_KEY, 
    secretAccessKey: process.env.DO_SPACES_SECRET, 
  },
  endpoint: process.env.DO_SPACES_ENDPOINT, // similar to this https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com
  forcePathStyle: true, // Required for some S3-compatible services
});

const deleteFile = async (keys) => {
  try {
    const keys = [
      "[spacename]/1702039720121672541410-file_example_JPG_2500kB.jpg",
      "[spacename]/1702034408592871178538-file_example_PNG_2100kB.png",
      "[spacename]/1702034501011992084344-file_example_PNG_3MB.png",
    ];
    const keysArray = [];
    keys.map((key) => keysArray.push({ Key: key }));
    console.log(keysArray);
    const deleteParams = {
      Bucket: process.env.DO_SPACES_NAME, 
      Delete: {
        Objects: keysArray,
        // Quiet: false, 
      },
    };

    const command = new DeleteObjectsCommand(deleteParams);
    const data = await s3.send(command).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err);
    });

    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error deleting file:", error);
    throw error;
  }
};

module.exports = deleteFile;
```